# Selenium to check log files

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Does anyone know if it is possible to use selenium WebDriver (im using java) to check for messages in log files?

Currently the only way to know if an action in the front end of our system has completed is to ssh into our servers and wait for confirmation from the log files. This is how the process is tested manually but now I need to automate that test. Is it possible to use selenium to check this out?

My current method to achieve this seems overly complex:

- Run actions in Front end
- Launch shell Script to check log files from Selenium Test (includes ssh to server as logs are stored there)
- Create "Action Completed" message in simple text file on server if logs show action is completed otherwise show "Action NOT completed"
- scp file back to my machine/VM
- read in file to eclipse
- Create method in test to check contents of file something like  if ("Action completed" message is returned -> continue) else (repeat from bullet point 2)

Is there a simpler way???

Comment: Selenium is not well suited for this. Are you using a test framework (JUnit/TestNG) to execute the tests? If so, you could use any Java-way to implement this.

Comment: Yes I am using JUnit to execute the tests. With java though, I still run into the same problems as to check the logs I need to ssh to the servers, run checks on the logs and send the results back to my machine. Is there a better way?

Comment: action completion can be found by identifying the element change when we navigate to new page, or we can keep a global variable which can be set as true/false while performing the transactions(like in Echo user interface - EchoServerTransaction.active="true/false").

Comment: Thanks everybody for your quick and detailed responses. I took a bit of what everyone said as I think I found a simpler solution. If you are interested, I now run all the shell commands in a separate method and bring the output of the log files back to my Eclipse console. From there its quite simple to run regex commands on the output and perform further actions all in one place. Its seems to work quite well. Next step is adding multi-threaded code so I can check the logs in the background whilst running other check, gulp

Answer (score 1):

Self Answer - After considering all the posts, this is the solution I came up with that works really well. I have wirtten a method which allows me to parse the logs using regex right from Eclipse. Below is the code with heavy commenting to show what I have done....

```
public void checkLogs() throws IOException{
    //create an empty string to hold the output 
    String s = null;

    // using the process API and runtime exec method to directly ssh in the client machine and run any command you like. I need the live logs so I used tail -f
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh user@ipaddress tail -f /location/file");
    // use buffered reader to bring the output of the command run on the clinet machine back to the output in eclipse. I also created an output for the error stream to help with debugging if the commands dont work as I am not directly looking at the output when I run the commands on the client machine
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

    // For my test I only want to continue with the clicks in the front end once I know the system has been reset. For our system this can only be checked in the logs. So I created a boolean flag  which will only become true once the regex I run matches lines from the output. Use a while loop with != null to check every line of the output
    boolean requestArrived = false;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s); // so I can see live what is happening. (great for debugging)
        //search for the specific string that lets me know the system has been started the reset. (can run any regex here)
        if(r.equalsIgnoreCase("system reset request received")){
            System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************");
            // Change the state of the boolean flag to true as we know now that the backend is ready to continue
            requestArrived = true;
        }

        if(t.equalsIgnoreCase("System reset has happened successfully"))// a secondary check to see when the system is ready to continue{
            System.out.println("##############################################################################################");
            //if both string that we are looking for have been received we can continue with the rest of the script
            if (requestArrived) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //close the terminal 
    p.destroy();

}
```

I hope that helps someone :)

Comment: you don't even use selenium in your answer to your own question about using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Add a special page to your site that tails the logfile.  Have a shared secret that selenium knows and the site if you need to keep the logfile confidential.  Then just visit that page and use the usual methods to check for strings

There may be some permissions problems to overcome: normally web applications shouldn't be able to see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

With the present solution you describe, Selenium is not really the right tool for the job (even though you could probably find a solution).

I can see several possible approaches:

1. Add a page that shows the progress (as suggested by Vorsprung). This could be a separate page, or some message in the existing GUI. This could be only for Selenium, or maybe it could even become a proper feature for all users (or only for administrators), if it makes sense for your system.
2. Use a system like you describe, but run the server on the local system (as a special test instance). Then you can skip the SSHing.
3. Create some service (REST or similar) on the server to query job status. Again, this may be useful for more than just testing.

What makes sense depends on how the system is used (how users currently check whether a job has completed, what information about a job is interesting, etc.).

Comment: Thanks everybody for your quick and detailed responses. I took a bit of what everyone said as I think I found a simpler solution. If you are interested, I now run all the shell commands in a separate method and bring the output of the log files back to my Eclipse console. From there its quite simple to run regex commands on the output and perform further actions all in one place. Its seems to work quite well. Next step is adding multi-threaded code so I can check the logs in the background whilst running other check, ***gulp***

Comment: @DanielCohen: I'm glad you found a solution for your problem. Consider adding your solution as an answer - self-answers are encouraged here, to help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misread your question, As you were asking for a simpler solution, but I tried to provide solution for the complex approach. Anyways I hope it will be useful.

**Actual Answer:**

I had done following activity for my project

1. clear logs using a shell script on remote unix server
2. Perform front end activity
3. capture logs after predefined time (say, 60 seconds )
4. SFtp back to client machine

first you will need an SFTP client and SSH client to interact with unix server
here Node is an object containing Unix env details. so change accordingly.
Using **JSch** lib for this

```
public static String runCommand(String Command, Node node )
{
    String output = null;
    if (node.getConnType().equals("SSH")){
        int exitStatus = 0;
        try{
              JSch jsch=new JSch();  

              JSch.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 

              Session session=jsch.getSession(node.getUserName(), node.getHost(), 22);

              session.setPassword(node.getPassword());
              session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                         "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");

              session.connect();

              String command=Command;

              Channel channel=session.openChannel("exec");
              ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(command);

              channel.setInputStream(null);
              ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
              InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();
              channel.connect();

              byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
              while(true){
                while(in.available()>0){
                  int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                  if(i<0)break;
                  output = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                }
                if(channel.isClosed()){
                  if(in.available()>0) continue; 
                  exitStatus= channel.getExitStatus();
                  //System.out.println("exit-status: "+exitStatus);
                  break;
                }
                try{Thread.sleep(1000);}catch(Exception ee){}
              }
              channel.disconnect();
              session.disconnect();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
           if (exitStatus == 0)
           {
               if(output != null)
                   return output.replaceAll("[\\n\\r]", "");
           }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

**SFTP client**

```
public boolean transferFileSFTP(Node node,String srcDir,String targetDir,String srcFileName,String targetFileName, String direction)
 {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession(node.getUserName(), node.getHost(), 22);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", 
                "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.setPassword(node.getPassword());
        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        System.out.println("src:" + srcDir+srcFileName );
        System.out.println("target:" + targetDir+targetFileName );
        sftpChannel.get(targetDir+targetFileName, srcDir+srcFileName);
        sftpChannel.exit();
        session.disconnect();
        return true;
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (SftpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now,
To wait until desired time and make it thread based to collect logs simultaneously from different applications involved,
using **ExecutorService** and **Future<String>** utilities

So created one LogCollector class which will initiate request and another is ThreadClass(logical) which will perform activities on log file.

**LogCollector.java**

```
public class LogCollector {

    private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    private static List<Future<String>> list = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();    

    public static void add(Node node, String srcDir, String targetDir, String srcFileName, String targetFileName, long wait )
    {
        list.add(pool.submit(new LogCollectorThread(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000,wait, srcDir,  targetDir,  srcFileName,  targetFileName, node )));                      
    }

    public static void getResult()
    {   
        try{
            for (Future<String> future : list) {
                String out =future.get();
                //DO whatever you want to do with a response string return from your thread class
            }
            pool.shutdown();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }     
    } 

}
```

**LogCollectorThread.java**

```
public class LogCollectorThread implements Callable<String>{
    long startTime;
    long wait;
    String srcFileName;
    String targetFileName;
    String srcDir;
    String targetDir;
    Node node;

    public LogCollectorThread(long startTime, long wait,String srcDir, String targetDir,String srcFileName, String targetFileName, 
             Node node) {
        super();
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.wait = wait;
        this.srcFileName = srcFileName;
        this.targetFileName = targetFileName;
        this.srcDir = srcDir;
        this.targetDir = targetDir;
        this.node = node;
    }
    /***
     * Returns a String with Parameters separated by ',' and status at the end 
     * status values:
     *   0 - successfully retrieved log file
     *   1 - failure while retrieving log file
     */
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        while((System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - startTime)<=wait)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        MyFTPClient sftp= new MyFTPClient();
        boolean result =sftp.transferFileSFTP(this.node, this.srcDir, this.targetDir, this.srcFileName, this.targetFileName, "From");
        System.out.println(this.node.getHost() + ","+ this.srcDir + ","+this.targetDir +","+ this.srcFileName +","+ this.targetFileName);
        if(result == true)
            return this.node.getHost() + ","+ this.srcDir + ","+this.targetDir +","+ this.srcFileName +","+ this.targetFileName +"," + "0" ;
        else
            return this.node.getHost() + ","+ this.srcDir + ","+this.targetDir +","+ this.srcFileName +","+ this.targetFileName +"," + "1" ;
     }
}
```

**How to use LogCollector classes:**

```
 String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    Helper.runCommand("cd /opt/redknee/app/crm/current/log/; echo > AppCrm.log", testEnv.getBSS());

    LogCollector.add(testEnv.getBSS(), "collectedLogs\\", "/opt/redknee/app/crm/current/log/", timeStamp + "_" + testEnv.getBSS().getHost() + "_BSS_AppCrm.log"  , "AppCrm.log", 60);

    //So your thread is working now, so now perform your Front End Activity
    //After 60 seconds, log file will be SFTPed to client host
    //You can perform you activity before adding logCollectorThread or just before that

    LogCollector.getResult();
```

Here I have given too much code, 
But it is too hard to describe each step line by line.
**Main thing i wanted to prove is using java most of the things are possible.
It is upto you to decide how critical it is and is it worth doing.**

**Now coming to your exact requirement of searching for a particular string.**

As you can see in logCollectorThread,
currently i am doing nothing but just waiting till 60 seconds to complete.
So here you can use runCommand to grep desired string from logs
you can use command like

```
 grep -i  "Action Completed" | grep -v 'grep' | wc -l
```

if it return 1, you found your string
Similarly you can check for failure message.
and return desired string from your thread and get it as result in threadCollector.getResult() method.

And Once file is FTPed to your client, parsing it for a particular string using Java would be very easy. StackOverflow will help you in that :)

declaimer: don't expect code to be fully working.
It will work but you have to put your efforts. your java knowledge will be needed to plug-in the missing pieces

Answer (score -1):

To check the action got completed, checking server logs might be solution. But still in GUI, we could see visibility of some html elements or messages or java script variable or overriding javscript functions.

With the help of [Selenium JavscriptExecutor](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html), we can override [alert method](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver) (refer example 21)similarly we can override onreadystatechange for the request/response completion.

JavaScript Window variables can be used to show the action completeness by checking [after each ajax request](http://txs.io/6e2b).

We can use selenium wait to wait for an element to be visible, identify an element [using xpath](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-verify-element-is-enabled-or.html).

There are more tutorials available in the below link for element wait, typing in textbox and so on.
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2014/05/selenium-webdriver-tutorials-part-two.html